# DocumentComplete event in Embedded IWebBrowser2 using write() method

Tags: c++, winapi, com, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I've been looking hard for this but still have not found any solution. I'm using native win32 c++ (no MFC, ATL or .NET)

**I'm loading an html document with IHTMLDocument2->write().
I would like to get the event when the page is ready to show, meaning that all images and elements are downloaded and rendered.**

Following the embedded browser object from here [embedded web control (IWebBrowser2), embedded javascript's onkeydown and onkeyup not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904176/embedded-web-control-iwebbrowser2-embedded-javascripts-onkeydown-and-onkeyup) and from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla I managed to get an embedded web browser working fine and loading an html bstr.

I modified the control as shown below.
Now I can get the events from the document but never getting DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE.
The only workaround to get this event is when in the html there is an iframe with src attribute:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <iframe src="...">...</iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the window created by `<iframe src="...">` launches the DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE when the src is ready to show. (It requires to refresh the browser after writting the content)

If the `<iframe>` has no "src" then the event is fired but the iframe content is never rendered.

In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282.aspx it says that one documentComplete event will be fired for each window in the document, but as I am not using "Navigate" to load the html content and DocumentComplete never gets fired, I suspect that DocumentComplete only gets fired after "Navigate", not when using "write()" neither when using "write() + close()" to load html.

I've also tried to override "its" internet protocol, so when navigating to "its://..." I managed to load the document (idea from here: http://sumatrapdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/utils/HtmlWindow.cpp). Then I got DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE for each navigation, but after 10-12 navigations the program chrashes (it released the EventSink object more times than refferenced... weird). After days of trying I concluded that I'm not so experienced to get this working and as it was not a really nice solution, just an ugly workaround, I decided to go back to IHTMLDocument2->write().

I've also tried to attach to DIID_HTMLDocumentEvents2 the get DISPID_HTMLELEMENTEVENTS2_ONREADYSTATECHANGE but no success at all.

Please, any solution?

EmbBrowser.h:

(EmbBrowserEventSink is a simple IDIspatch implementation and IBrowserEventListener is an interface with onDocumentComplete and onClick methods)

```
    #pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <Exdisp.h>
#include <comdef.h> // for variant_t
#include <exception>
#include <mshtml.h>    // Defines of stuff like IHTMLDocument2. This is an include file with Visual C 6 and above

#include "EmbBrowserEventSink.h"

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class EmbBrowser : public IUnknown, public IOleClientSite, public IOleInPlaceSite, public IStorage{
public:
  EmbBrowser(HWND _mainWindow, IBrowserEventListener *browserEventListener = NULL);
  ~EmbBrowser();

  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE setEventListener(IBrowserEventListener *browserEventListener) {
    this->mBrowserEventListener = browserEventListener;
    return S_OK;
  };
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE hideScrollBars();
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE displayHTMLStr(LPCTSTR htmlSource);
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE pixelToHiMetric(const RECT& _rc, RECT *_metricRc);
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE setRect(const RECT &_rc);
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE adjustSize(HWND hWnd);
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE navigate(LPCTSTR _url);

  // ----- IUnknown -----

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void**ppvObject) override;
  virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void) override { return ++m_comRefCount; };
  virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release( void) override  {
    if (!--m_comRefCount) {
      delete this;
    }
    return m_comRefCount;
  };

  // ---------- IOleWindow ----------

  virtual /* [input_sync] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetWindow(/* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt HWND *phwnd) override;
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ContextSensitiveHelp( /* [in] */ BOOL fEnterMode) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  // ---------- IOleInPlaceSite ----------

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CanInPlaceActivate(void) override { return S_OK; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnInPlaceActivate(void) override;
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnUIActivate(void) override { return S_OK; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetWindowContext( 
    /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleInPlaceFrame **ppFrame,
    /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleInPlaceUIWindow **ppDoc,
    /* [out] */ __RPC__out LPRECT lprcPosRect,
    /* [out] */ __RPC__out LPRECT lprcClipRect,
    /* [out][in] */ __RPC__inout LPOLEINPLACEFRAMEINFO lpFrameInfo) override;

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Scroll(/* [in] */ SIZE scrollExtant) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnUIDeactivate(/* [in] */ BOOL fUndoable) override { return S_OK; };
  virtual HWND    STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetControlWindow();
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnInPlaceDeactivate(void) override;
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DiscardUndoState(void) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DeactivateAndUndo(void) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnPosRectChange(/* [in] */ __RPC__in LPCRECT lprcPosRect) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  // ---------- IOleClientSite ----------

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SaveObject(void) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetMoniker(
    /* [in] */ DWORD dwAssign,
    /* [in] */ DWORD dwWhichMoniker,
    /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IMoniker **ppmk) override
  {
    if((dwAssign == OLEGETMONIKER_ONLYIFTHERE) && (dwWhichMoniker == OLEWHICHMK_CONTAINER)) {
      return E_FAIL;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL;
  };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetContainer(/* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleContainer **ppContainer) override { return E_NOINTERFACE; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ShowObject( void) override { return S_OK; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnShowWindow( /* [in] */ BOOL fShow) override { return S_OK; };;
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RequestNewObjectLayout( void) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  // ----- IStorage -----

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateStream( 
    /* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR *pwcsName,
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfMode,
    /* [in] */ DWORD reserved1,
    /* [in] */ DWORD reserved2,
    /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IStream **ppstm) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OpenStream( 
    /* [string][in] */ const OLECHAR *pwcsName,
    /* [unique][in] */ void *reserved1,
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfMode,
    /* [in] */ DWORD reserved2,
    /* [out] */ IStream **ppstm) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateStorage( 
    /* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR *pwcsName,
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfMode,
    /* [in] */ DWORD reserved1,
    /* [in] */ DWORD reserved2,
    /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IStorage **ppstg) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OpenStorage( 
    /* [string][unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt_string const OLECHAR *pwcsName,
    /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt IStorage *pstgPriority,
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfMode,
    /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__deref_opt_in_opt SNB snbExclude,
    /* [in] */ DWORD reserved,
    /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IStorage **ppstg) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CopyTo( 
    /* [in] */ DWORD ciidExclude,
    /* [size_is][unique][in] */ const IID *rgiidExclude,
    /* [annotation][unique][in] */ 
    __RPC__in_opt  SNB snbExclude,
    /* [unique][in] */ IStorage *pstgDest) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE MoveElementTo( 
    /* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR *pwcsName,
    /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt IStorage *pstgDest,
    /* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR *pwcsNewName,
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfFlags) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Commit(/* [in] */ DWORD grfCommitFlags) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Revert(void) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EnumElements( 
    /* [in] */ DWORD reserved1,
    /* [size_is][unique][in] */ void *reserved2,
    /* [in] */ DWORD reserved3,
    /* [out] */ IEnumSTATSTG **ppenum) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DestroyElement(/* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR *pwcsName) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RenameElement( 
    /* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR *pwcsOldName,
    /* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string const OLECHAR *pwcsNewName) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetElementTimes( 
    /* [string][unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt_string const OLECHAR *pwcsName,
    /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME *pctime,
    /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME *patime,
    /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt const FILETIME *pmtime) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetClass(/* [in] */ __RPC__in REFCLSID clsid) override { return S_OK; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetStateBits( 
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfStateBits,
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfMask) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };

  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Stat( 
    /* [out] */ __RPC__out STATSTG *pstatstg,
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfStatFlag) override { return E_NOTIMPL; };


protected:
private:
  IOleObject            *m_oleObject;
  LONG                  m_comRefCount;
  HWND                  m_mainWindow;
  RECT                  m_objectRect;
  IWebBrowser2          *m_webBrowser;
  IOleInPlaceObject     *m_oleInPlaceObject;
  HWND                  m_controlWindow;
  DWORD                 mAdviseBrowserEventsCookie;
  IBrowserEventListener *mBrowserEventListener;
  EmbBrowserEventSink   *mEmbBrowserEventSink;

  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE connectEvents();
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE disconnectEvents();
};
```

EmbBrowser.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "EmbBrowser.h"

EmbBrowser::EmbBrowser(HWND _mainWindow, IBrowserEventListener *browserEventListener) : m_mainWindow(_mainWindow),
  mBrowserEventListener(browserEventListener), m_comRefCount(0), mEmbBrowserEventSink(NULL), mAdviseBrowserEventsCookie(0)
{
  ::SetRect(&m_objectRect, -300, -300, 300, 300);

  HRESULT hr = ::OleCreate(CLSID_WebBrowser, IID_IOleObject, OLERENDER_DRAW, 0, this, this, (void**)&m_oleObject);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    throw new exception("OleCreate() failed");
  }

  hr = m_oleObject->SetClientSite(this);
  hr = OleSetContainedObject(m_oleObject, TRUE);

  if (FAILED(m_oleObject->DoVerb(OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE, NULL, this, -1, m_mainWindow, &m_objectRect))) {
    throw new exception("DoVerb(OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE) failed");
  }

  hr = m_oleObject->QueryInterface(&m_webBrowser);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    throw new exception("QueryInterface(IWebBrowser) failed");
  }

  this->navigate(L"about:blank");
}

EmbBrowser::~EmbBrowser() {
  this->m_webBrowser->Release();
  this->m_oleObject->Close(OLECLOSE_NOSAVE);
  this->m_oleObject->Release();
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::navigate(LPCTSTR _url) {
  BSTR url;
  url = SysAllocString(_url);
  variant_t flags(0x02u); // navNoHistory;
  HRESULT hr = m_webBrowser->Navigate(url, &flags, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  SysFreeString(url);

  return hr;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::hideScrollBars() {
  HRESULT           hr;
  IDispatch         *pDocDispatch = 0;
  IHTMLDocument2    *pHtmlDocument = 0;
  IHTMLElement      *pBodyElm = 0;
  IHTMLBodyElement  *pBody = 0;
  VARIANT           v;

  hr = m_webBrowser->get_Document(&pDocDispatch);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pDocDispatch) {
    goto hideScrollBar_clean;
  }

  hr = pDocDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void **) &pHtmlDocument);
  if (FAILED(hr) && !pHtmlDocument) {
    goto hideScrollBar_clean;
  }

  hr = pHtmlDocument->get_body(&pBodyElm);
  if (FAILED(hr) && !pBodyElm) {
    goto hideScrollBar_clean;
  }

  hr = pBodyElm->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLBodyElement, (void **) &pBody);
  if (FAILED(hr) && !pBody) {
    goto hideScrollBar_clean;
  }

  v.vt = VT_INT;
  v.intVal = 0;

  pBody->put_scroll(L"no");
  pBody->put_leftMargin(v);
  pBody->put_topMargin(v);


hideScrollBar_clean:

  if (pBody) {
    pBody->Release();
  }
  if (pBodyElm) {
    pBodyElm->Release();
  }
  if (pHtmlDocument) {
    pHtmlDocument->Release();
  }
  if (pDocDispatch) {
    pDocDispatch->Release();
  }

  return hr;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::displayHTMLStr(LPCTSTR htmlSource) {
  // This is used by DisplayHTMLStr(). It can be global because we never change it.
  static const SAFEARRAYBOUND ArrayBound = {1, 0};

  HRESULT                   hr;

  IDispatch                 *pDispatch = 0;
  IHTMLDocument2            *pHtmlDoc2 = 0;
  SAFEARRAY                 *sfArray = 0;
  VARIANT                   *pVar = 0;
  BSTR                      bstr = 0;

  hr = m_webBrowser->get_Document(&pDispatch);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pDispatch) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void **) &pHtmlDoc2);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pHtmlDoc2) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  // Our HTML must be in the form of a BSTR. And it must be passed to write() in an
  // array of "VARIENT" structs. So let's create all that.
  sfArray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, (SAFEARRAYBOUND *) &ArrayBound);
  if (!sfArray) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  hr = SafeArrayAccessData(sfArray, (void**) &pVar);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  pVar->vt = VT_BSTR;

#ifndef UNICODE
  {
    wchar_t    *buffer;
    DWORD      size;

    size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, htmlSource, -1, 0, 0);
    if (!(buffer = (wchar_t *)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, sizeof(wchar_t) * size))) {
      goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
    }
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, htmlSource, -1, buffer, size);
    bstr = SysAllocString(buffer);
    GlobalFree(buffer);
  }
#else
  bstr = SysAllocString(htmlSource);
#endif

  if (!bstr) {
    hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  // Connect HTMLDocumentEvents2 to get onDocumentComplete and onClick events
  this->connectEvents();

  //mEmbBrowserEventSink->setFinishedWriting(false);
  hr = pHtmlDoc2->clear();
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  hr = pHtmlDoc2->write(sfArray);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  hr = pHtmlDoc2->close();
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  //mEmbBrowserEventSink->setFinishedWriting(true);
  //hr = m_webBrowser->Refresh();
  //if (FAILED(hr)) {
  //  goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  //}

  //this->mBrowserEventListener->onDocumentComplete(true);


displayHTMLStr_clean:

  // Normally, we'd need to free our BSTR, but SafeArrayDestroy() does it for us
  // SysFreeString(bstr);
  if (bstr) {
    SysFreeString(bstr);
  }
  if (sfArray) {
    // SafeArrayDestroy(sfArray);
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(sfArray);
  }
  if (pHtmlDoc2) {
    pHtmlDoc2->Release();
  }
  if (pDispatch) {
    pDispatch->Release();
  }

  return hr;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::connectEvents() {
  HRESULT                   hr;
  IConnectionPointContainer *pCPC = 0;
  IConnectionPoint          *pCP = 0;
  IUnknown                  *pUnkEventSink = 0;

  this->disconnectEvents();

  this->mEmbBrowserEventSink = new EmbBrowserEventSink(m_webBrowser, this->mBrowserEventListener);
  hr = this->mEmbBrowserEventSink->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void **) &pUnkEventSink);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pUnkEventSink) {
    goto connectEvents_clean;
  }

  hr = /*pHtmlDoc2*/m_webBrowser->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void **) &pCPC);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pCPC) {
    goto connectEvents_clean;
  }

  hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint(/*DIID_HTMLDocumentEvents2*/ DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &pCP);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pCP) {
    goto connectEvents_clean;
  }

  hr = pCP->Advise(pUnkEventSink, &mAdviseBrowserEventsCookie);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    goto connectEvents_clean;
  }

connectEvents_clean:

  if (pCP) {
    pCP->Release();
  }
  if (pCPC) {
    pCPC->Release();
  }
  if (pUnkEventSink) {
    pUnkEventSink->Release();
  }

  return hr;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::disconnectEvents() {
  HRESULT                   hr;
  IDispatch                 *pDispatch = 0;
  IHTMLDocument2            *pHtmlDoc2 = 0;
  IConnectionPointContainer *pCPC = 0;
  IConnectionPoint          *pCP = 0;

  if (!mAdviseHTMLEventsCookie) {
    hr = S_OK;
    goto disconnectHtmlEvents_clean;
  }

  //hr = m_webBrowser->get_Document(&pDispatch);
  //if (FAILED(hr) || !pDispatch) {
  //  goto disconnectHtmlEvents_clean;
  //}

  //hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void **) &pHtmlDoc2);
  //if (FAILED(hr) || !pHtmlDoc2) {
  //  goto disconnectHtmlEvents_clean;
  //}

  hr = /*pHtmlDoc2*/this->m_webBrowser->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void **) &pCPC);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pCPC) {
    goto disconnectHtmlEvents_clean;
  }

  hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint(/*DIID_HTMLDocumentEvents2*/ DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &pCP);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pCP) {
    goto disconnectHtmlEvents_clean;
  }

  hr = pCP->Unadvise(mAdviseBrowserEventsCookie);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    goto disconnectHtmlEvents_clean;
  }

  mAdviseBrowserEventsCookie= 0;


disconnectHtmlEvents_clean:
  if (pCP) {
    pCP->Release();
  }
  if (pCPC) {
    pCPC->Release();
  }
  if (pHtmlDoc2) {
    pHtmlDoc2->Release();
  }
  if (pDispatch) {
    pDispatch->Release();
  }

  return hr;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::pixelToHiMetric(const RECT& _rc, RECT *_metricRc) {
  static bool s_initialized = false;
  static int s_pixelsPerInchX, s_pixelsPerInchY;

  if (!_metricRc) {
    return E_INVALIDARG;
  }

  if (!s_initialized) {
    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);
    s_pixelsPerInchX = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
    s_pixelsPerInchY = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
    ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    s_initialized = true;
  }

  RECT rc;
  _metricRc->left = MulDiv(2540, _rc.left, s_pixelsPerInchX);
  _metricRc->top = MulDiv(2540, _rc.top, s_pixelsPerInchY);
  _metricRc->right = MulDiv(2540, _rc.right, s_pixelsPerInchX);
  _metricRc->bottom = MulDiv(2540, _rc.bottom, s_pixelsPerInchY);

  return S_OK;
}


HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::setRect(const RECT &_rc) {
  HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

  m_objectRect = _rc;

  {
    RECT hiMetricRect;
    hr = pixelToHiMetric(m_objectRect, &hiMetricRect);
    SIZEL sz;
    sz.cx = hiMetricRect.right - hiMetricRect.left;
    sz.cy = hiMetricRect.bottom - hiMetricRect.top;
    m_oleObject->SetExtent(DVASPECT_CONTENT, &sz);
  }

  if (m_oleInPlaceObject != NULL) {
    hr = m_oleInPlaceObject->SetObjectRects(&m_objectRect, &m_objectRect);
  }

  return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::adjustSize(HWND hWnd) {
  RECT rc;
  GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
  rc.bottom -= rc.top;
  rc.top    -= rc.top;
  rc.right  -= rc.left;
  rc.left   -= rc.left;

  return setRect(rc);
}

// -----== IUnknown ==----->

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject) {

  if (riid == __uuidof(IUnknown)) {
    (*ppvObject) = static_cast<IUnknown *> (this);

  } else if (riid == __uuidof(IOleClientSite)) {
    (*ppvObject) = static_cast<IOleClientSite *> (this);

  } else if (riid == __uuidof(IOleInPlaceSite)) {
    (*ppvObject) = static_cast<IOleInPlaceSite *> (this);

  } else if(riid == __uuidof(IStorage)) {
    (*ppvObject) = static_cast<IStorage *> (this);

  } else if (riid == __uuidof(IOleWindow)) {
    (*ppvObject) = static_cast<IOleWindow *> (this);

  } else {
    (*ppvObject) = 0;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
  }

  AddRef(); // implicit AddRef()

  return S_OK;
}

// ----------== IOleWindow ==---------->

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::GetWindow(__RPC__deref_out_opt HWND *phwnd) {
  (*phwnd) = m_mainWindow;

  return S_OK;
}

// ----------== IOleInPlaceSite ==---------->

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::OnInPlaceActivate(void) {
  OleLockRunning(m_oleObject, TRUE, FALSE);
  m_oleObject->QueryInterface(&m_oleInPlaceObject);
  m_oleInPlaceObject->SetObjectRects(&m_objectRect, &m_objectRect);

  return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::GetWindowContext(__RPC__deref_out_opt IOleInPlaceFrame **ppFrame,
                                                       __RPC__deref_out_opt IOleInPlaceUIWindow **ppDoc,
                                                       __RPC__out LPRECT lprcPosRect,__RPC__out LPRECT lprcClipRect,
                                                       __RPC__inout LPOLEINPLACEFRAMEINFO lpFrameInfo)
{
  HWND hwnd = m_mainWindow;

  (*ppFrame) = NULL;
  (*ppDoc) = NULL;
  (*lprcPosRect).left   = m_objectRect.left;
  (*lprcPosRect).top    = m_objectRect.top;
  (*lprcPosRect).right  = m_objectRect.right;
  (*lprcPosRect).bottom = m_objectRect.bottom;
  *lprcClipRect = *lprcPosRect;

  lpFrameInfo->fMDIApp = false;
  lpFrameInfo->hwndFrame = hwnd;
  lpFrameInfo->haccel = NULL;
  lpFrameInfo->cAccelEntries = 0;

  return S_OK;
}

HWND STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::GetControlWindow() {
  if(m_controlWindow != NULL) {
    return m_controlWindow;
  }

  if(m_oleInPlaceObject == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  m_oleInPlaceObject->GetWindow(&m_controlWindow);

  return m_controlWindow;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::OnInPlaceDeactivate(void) {
  m_controlWindow = NULL;
  m_oleInPlaceObject = NULL;

  return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I also do IHTMLDocument2->write in an embebded WebBrowser control, and I get the DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, so "it should work" for you. BUT: I dont' see the ->write in your source!?!

Comment: Never mind, found it :-)

Comment: Using `write()` is not the best way to load HTML from memory. Query the document for `IPersistStreamInit` and call its `Load()` method instead.  You will need to store your HTML in an `IStream` implementation that you can pass to `Load()`.

Comment: Good! I had already tried with IPersistStreamInit but maybe I made something wrong. Now I'm getting the events. Kind of weird.

Comment: This question is the best quick 'how-to' manual for pure WinAPI handling of IE events. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Remy, I tried again loading with IPersistStreamInit and now it seems to be working.
Here it is the new displayHTMLStr():

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmbBrowser::displayHTMLStr(LPCTSTR htmlSource) {
  HRESULT                   hr;

  IDispatch                 *pDispatch = 0;
  IHTMLDocument2            *pHtmlDoc2 = 0;
  IPersistStreamInit        *pPSI = 0;
  IStream                   *pStream = 0;
  HGLOBAL                   hHTMLContent;

  hr = m_webBrowser->get_Document(&pDispatch);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pDispatch) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void **) &pHtmlDoc2);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pHtmlDoc2) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  hr = pHtmlDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistStreamInit, (void **) &pPSI);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pPSI) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  // allocate global memory to copy the HTML content to
  hHTMLContent = ::GlobalAlloc(GPTR, (::_tcslen(htmlSource) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
  if (!hHTMLContent) {
    hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  ::_tcscpy((TCHAR *) hHTMLContent, htmlSource);

  // create a stream object based on the HTML content
  hr = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hHTMLContent, TRUE, &pStream);
  if (FAILED(hr) || !pStream) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  hr = pPSI->InitNew();
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
  }

  // Connect HTMLDocumentEvents2 to get onDocumentComplete and onClick events
  this->connectEvents();
  hr = pPSI->Load(pStream);

  _tprintf(_T("Written: \n%s\n\n"), htmlSource);


displayHTMLStr_clean:

  if (pStream) {
    pStream->Release();
  }
  if (hHTMLContent) {
    GlobalFree(hHTMLContent);
  }
  if (pPSI) {
    pPSI->Release();
  }
  if (pHtmlDoc2) {
    pHtmlDoc2->Release();
  }
  if (pDispatch) {
    pDispatch->Release();
  }

  return hr;
}
```