# webbrowser control - make sure that all frames were loaded (alternative to "DocumentCompleted")

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing a program that navigates through a website containing a number of frames. I am using WinForms webBrowser control.

I had the same program written in visual basic script, where I have used the following code as a subprocedure to make sure that everything is loaded before trying to invoke click events etc.

```
Sub CheckIfLoaded
    Do while appIE.Busy = True OR appIE.ReadyState <> 4 : Wscript.Sleep(100) : Loop
End Sub
```

I am looking for something similar in C#. I don't think that WebBrowswer.DocumentCompleted event is the solution here, because as far as I understand the usage of it, I would have to put whole code into one `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` method in a large number of `if` statements, which seems really wrong.

The pseudo code would be:

```
private void DoOneSpecificThing (string[] ListOfThings)
{
    foreach (string ID in ListOfThings)
    {
      open webbrowser and navigate to page;
       CheckIfLoaded();
      Log In and load the first page;
       CheckIfLoaded();
      Tick a bunch of tickboxes, write in textboxes etc;
      Submit;
       CheckIfLoaded();
      Go to the next page;
       CheckIfLoaded();
      And do more stuff;
      Submit;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of procedures like that in my code (e.g. for logging in, for navigating to selected page, for filling forms, for setting options, for generating reports), so I would like to have one simple thing that would make sure that the page is loaded before trying to access its element, as I had in vbs.

I tried the following two solutions:
(in the first one, the application never gets to load a page)

```
        int counter = 0;
        while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            counter += 1;
        }
```

(in the second, the application doesn't actually wait for the page to load, so I tend to get null reference errors and this kind of stuff `InvalidArgument=Value of 'nav' is not valid for 'windowId'.`)

```
        while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Bartosz

Comment: A browser is (hopefully) multithreaded. Using events (when they are available) is much better than doing while+sleep+doevents loops. But yes, it can be more difficult to grasp from a developer perspective. you should start learning async programming.

Comment: I have just started learning programming, so this may be a bit too complicated for now. So you don't see any way to make sure that the browser has loaded everything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentComplete event in Embedded IWebBrowser2 using write() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286451/documentcomplete-event-in-embedded-iwebbrowser2-using-write-method)